# http header redirect from multiple sources

Tags: php, nginx, https, http-redirect

This is my working setup

**Main-Page --> Forum-Page**

You can only access the Forum-Page when you are coming from Main-Page. If you access Forum-Page from anywhere else you get back to Main-Page.

Here's the code on my Forum-Page and it works as intended

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=='https://homepage.com/folder/mainpage.php')
{
    header('Location: https://homepage.com/folder/mainpage.php');
    exit;
}
```

BUT

if I come back from a Forum-Subpage I also get back to Main-Page.
A Forum-Page looks like this

https://homepage.com/folder/forumpage.php?page=view&entry=16

This is what I want to achieve

**Main-Page --> Forum-Page <-- Forum-Subpages**

So now I need another rule on my Forum-Page that also accept a return from a Forum-Subpage. Since I can't define every subpage I want to add a wildcard at the end like this

https://homepage.com/folder/forumpage.php?page=*

I just don't know how to add this with a correct syntax to my first rule above to make this work. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, since I'm new can you please let me know what I did wrong here to get a downvote on my question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=='https://homepage.com/folder/mainpage.php' 
    && substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, 47) !== 'https://homepage.com/folder/forumpage.php?page=')
{
    header('Location: https://homepage.com/folder/mainpage.php');
    exit;
}
```

This setup worries me though. I wouldn't to rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_Referer']`; browsers are not guaranteed to set it properly or at all. It especially concerns me that the question is tagged with security as this provides no real security.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this is of course not a security solution. It is just an additional layer on top of other measures I already have in place. So you are right - the security badge is misleading and will be removed

Comment: Can you post what `substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, 47)` is returning?

Comment: my php error log reads `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in` and references the line number with susbtr

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. It could technically be that the browser isn't sending the referer data, but if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is undefined, your existing code shouldn't work either. Are the two variable names identical?

Comment: here's the complete code `if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=='https://example.com/myfolder/gate.php'
&& substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, 47) !== 'https://example.com/myfolder/subfolder/page.php?page=')`

Comment: And it wasn't generating the error before with your code? That seems really odd. I guess you could do something like `$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`, then use `$referer` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. I am very confused as to where the problem is here. It's like the index exists and then it doesn't.